# Why isn't this working? Java MySQL

Tags: java, mysql

```
package me.martinwiesner.mysqltest;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DBConnect {

    // Driver
    static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    // URL
    static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://host:port/name";

    static final String USER = "username";
    static final String PASS = "password";

    public static List<User> getAllUsers() {
        List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();

        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        try {
            Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);

            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);

            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            String sql;
            sql = "SELECT id, first name, last name, email, password, admin FROM users";
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);


            while (rs.next()) {

                int id = rs.getInt("id");
                String firstName = rs.getString("first name");
                String lastName = rs.getString("last name");
                String email = rs.getString("email");
                String password = rs.getString("password");
                boolean isAdmin = Boolean.getBoolean(rs.getString("admin"));

                User u = new User(email, firstName, lastName, password, isAdmin, id);
                users.add(u);
            }
            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            conn.close();

        } catch (SQLException se) {
            System.out.println("1");
            return null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("2");
            return null;

        } finally {
            try {
                if (stmt != null)
                    stmt.close();
            } catch (SQLException se2) {
                System.out.println("3");
                users = null;
            }

            try {
                if (conn != null)
                    conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException se) {
                System.out.println("4");
                users = null;
            }
        }

        return users;
    }
}
```

I am trying to access my database but it isn't working, it returns null. 
The exception:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'first' in 'field list'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:387)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:941)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3870)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3806)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2470)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2617)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2546)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2504)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1370)
    at me.martinwiesner.mysqltest.DBConnect.getAllUsers(DBConnect.java:34)
    at me.martinwiesner.mysqltest.Main.main(Main.java:12)
```

I changed my username, password, host, port and name. Else everybody could access my database.

Comment: You should call e.printStackTrace()

Comment: *"it returns null"* What returns null?

Comment: Don't put "paste-bin" links into questions.  They disappear quickly.  Instead copy the exception stacktrace into the questions ... as TEXT.

Answer (score 0):

> Why isn't this working?

It isn't working because something is throwing as exception.  (Duh!)

But since you are throwing away the exception information and simply returning `null`, we can't give you any more information as to *why* an exception is being thrown, or where.

Advice:

1. Unexpected exceptions should not be "squashed".  At the very least, print or log the stack trace.
2. Catching exceptions and returning `null` is generally a bad idea.  Now you have replaced the original failure with a potential new one; i.e. a `NullPointerException` when you don't test for the `null` ...
3. Catching `Exception` is almost always a bad idea.  It catches all sorts of unexpected things, many of which are liable to be caused by programming errors.  It is typically best to let (at least) *unchecked* exceptions propagate to something that can report them as an application error and terminate the application.

Comment: Ah yes.  Did you **read** the exception message?  It explains what the problem is.  Your SQL doesn't match the definition of your table.  (It looks like you have a spurious spaces in the field names in your SQL.)

Comment: I did read it, sorry but this is the first time I did something with MySQL and I am bad at understanding Exceptions and stuff.... It says 'first' but I wrote 'first name', what is wrong with it?
Thanks

Comment: Well "first name" is not a valid SQL identifier.  SQL field names don't normally have spaces in them.  I would say that the SQL parser has interpreted that as some alternative syntax where "first" is the name and "name" is ... something else.  If you want to use a field name with spaces in it, the name must be quoted ... see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html